# How to make the use user input to create an instance of a class?

Tags: python

I'm making a text-based adventure game in python and would like the user to choose a race and create an instance of a race class based on their choice. For example, if the player chose a Lizardman race from this code:

```
def character_creation():
    print("You have four choices, choose wisely")
    races = ['Lizard', 'Bookshelf', 'Genie', 'Werepus']

    while True:
        for i, j in enumerate(races):
            print(f"[{i + 1}]", j)

        choice = int(input('Pick a race:'))

        if choice <= len(races):
            print('You are a ', races[choice])
            return races[choice]
        else:
            continue
```

How would I get my code to make a race object?

```
character = Race('Lizardman', 'Regrowth', 20)
```

Each race is created by `Race(Name, Passive, HP)` and each race has its own passive and hp associated with it. As in, I don't want to ask the user for the passive and the HP, just the race name.

Comment: Is Lizardman the name of a race?

Comment: Yes that is one of the races

Answer (score 3):

You can use classmethod here.

```
class Race:
    def __init__(name: str, passive: str, hp: int):
        self.name = name
        self.passive = passive
        self.hp = hp

    @classmethod
    def from_race_name(cls, name):
        race_attributes = {'Lizardman':{'passive': 'Regrowth',
                                        'hp': 20,
                           .....}
        return cls(name, 
                   race_attributes[name]['passive'],
                   race_attributes[name]['hp'])
```

This will create an instance of the class based on only name of the race. To use it call it with the class name:

```
liz = Race.from_race_name('Lizardman')
```

This will create an instance of lizardman which will automatically be assigned 'regrowth' passive and 20 hp.

Also, if you want to create a 'unique' lizardman you can still do it manually:

```
admiral_akbar = Race(name='Lizardman', passive='panic', hp=999)
```

Comment: okay cool thank you, is that a decorator? I've never used one before and am unsure of what they do

Comment: Decorators just give special functionality to functions that use them. This is one of the standard decorators and it simply allows the method from inside the class to return an instance of that same class.

Comment: Check this out for example for a more detailed explanation: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/class-method-vs-static-method-python/

Answer (score 0):

If you want the user to only choose the race name and have everything else on default you can set the default values in the class parameters.

Here's an example:

```
class Race():
    def __init__(self, Name: str, Passive: str = "Regrowth", HP: int = 20): # Set default values here
        self.Name = Name
        self.Passive = Passive
        self.HP = HP

def Main():
    race_name = input("Pick a race: ")
    character = Race(race_name)
    print(character.Name, character.Passive, character.HP)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main()
```

Output if user enters '`Lizardman`':

```
Lizardman Regrowth 20
```

You can still overwrite and change the the Passive and the HP as so:

```
character = Race(Name = race_name, Passive = "Something", HP = 100)
```